# Google + button not displaying poperly

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-plus

I am trying to add social buttons to my site and I just cant bring the google+1 button closer to the the other social buttons. It just goes to the extreme left of the div.

I have put up the code in Jsfiddle please take a look

Here is how it is looking over at my end [image: The social media icons]
See how the google+ button is to the extreme left

JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LYYhj/3/

The code - HTML part

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=291527307526682";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<article class="grid_6">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <ul class="ul-1">
                <li><!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="inline" data-width="120" data-href="http://www.xgen-hosting.com" style="float:right;"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/XgenHosting" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @XgenHosting</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script></li>
                <li><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.xgen-hosting.com/" data-width="120" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </article>
```

The CSS part

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, .grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, .grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12 {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 10px
}
.wrapper{overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.ul-1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:right;
    padding:48px 3px 0 0;
}
.ul-1 li {
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    background:url(../images/ul-1.png) left 3px no-repeat;
    margin-left:8px;
    padding-left:8px;
    color:#ddd;
}
.ul-1 li:first-child {
    background:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.ul-1 li a {
    color:#ddd;
}
.ul-1 li a:hover {
    color:#f04011;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Also when I implement the code into my page the google+1 button moves up by a little and no matter what I do I just cant manage to bring it to align with the other social button.

Link to the page http://www.xgen-hosting.com

Comment: Huh...it appears fine for me. Chrome 31.

Comment: I guess its a browser issue then what browser are you on?

Comment: Have edited the post and added a screenshot for you @PaulDraper

Comment: Working fine on my chrome and firefox V.25.. (its google +, it should remain away from other social networks :D never mind)

Comment: haha but mate have a look into the page i am implementing it, it looks horrible with the google+ not only floating to the extreme left but it moves up too really messy :(

Comment: @RickRoy did you made some changes on page..? I was solving that..

Comment: Yea I am trying things out, do you need me to post the old code?

Comment: let me revert the index page back to the old one for you to solve, please check www.xgen-hosting.com I have got it reverted back to old state

Comment: yup..i will look into it..

Comment: Hey mate its working fine for in Chrome, Firefox 25 and Opera !!
Maybe there is some issue with your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two ways you can do this.

Method 1: If you inspect element the google+ button in your browser and see the code for `<li>` elements, you can see that width of the google plus button is 120px, decreasing it will make your google plus button to align with other `<li>` buttons.

Below is the pic of what I am trying to say and what I tried using this method.

[image: This is the inspect element part:]

and this is the result I got:

[image]

Now, the second method, if above doesn't work:

Make the list as `position: absolute;` This way you can position the buttons like whatever you want.

If you don't want to put the absolute positioned elements on the page (because there position will vary according to screen size), then you can simply put the absolute position list inside of a `<div>` which is positioned relatively.

Comment: Thanks @Butterfruit let me try it out btw did come up with my own solution while you were working on it, even though mine is a cheap fix kind of thing, you cant check my fix at www.xgen-hosting.com/test.html

Comment: could you please send me the code you are using, i did try and decrease the data-width from 120 to 30 but didn't see any change to my page

Comment: for the time being I am changing the code with the one i tested out, will revert back to yours when I get your code. Btw i dont want position: absolute; it will hamper the fluid nature of the page

Comment: I think on your main page, the g+ button is still not aligned. If you do not want to position absolute, then you can try with `table` instead of using list. That can also solve this glitch..